# jBPM 5: where are the db-tables-scripts?

Tags: database, jbpm

I created a simple example on persistence in JBPM 5.4. It worked successfully and the 
recoords were successfully inserted in the table in the schema created.

But my question is although the table was created in the schema it also created other three tables 
NodeInstanceLog
VariableInstanceLog
ProcessInstanceLog

but where are the scripts for creating these tables ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no scripts for the database.

The tables in the database are generated with JPA Entities.
For example entities SessionInfo, WorkItemInfo, ProcessInstanceInfo are classes with @ Entity annotation and the tables are created when you deploy jpbm-console-server.

Answer (score 0):

In your persistence.xml file the following hibernate entry is responsible for the db creation scripts assuming the persistence provider thats used for JPA is Hibernate.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
```