# JBPM - The 'Processinstacelog' table is showing status as integer instead of text datatype in Psotgres DB

Tags: postgresql, jbpm, kie-server

I am using JBPM with postgres DB. I have found in the postgres DB the default table that is 'Processinstancelog'. This table has the 'status' column but showing the 'status' as an integer value(like 1,2,3,4,...) and have data type as integer.

**Expected Requirement**

My requirement is to print 'status' in actual format(text) like, completed, exited, suspended, aborted, same as we have in the Business central work bench>Menu>Manage>process instance > state

**Query**

I did not find how the 'integer status' is mapped with 'textual status' in the "processinstancelog" table. there is no script for this table "processinstancelog" as this is the default created table.

**Question**

I want to know each number is mapped to which status? so I can print the status instead of numbers.

I found from the below question that Db has no script for the table 'processinstancelog'
[jBPM 5: where are the db-tables-scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14787484/jbpm-5-where-are-the-db-tables-scripts)

Also here is DB table screenshot
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3HdV.png)

Comment: what is the question? you want to know each number is mapped to which status?

Comment: Yes - I want to know each number is mapped to which status ? so I can print the status instead of the numbers

Comment: @Bashir - Yes - I want to know each number is mapped to which status ? so I can print the status instead of the numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list of integer-text mapping of process instance status:

```
 0 = STATE_PENDING, 
 1 = STATE_ACTIVE, 
 2 = STATE_COMPLETED,
 3 = STATE_ABORTED 
 4 = STATE_SUSPENDED
```